# Bootstrap inline checkboxes - How can I pull them left or right inside a form well?

Tags: html, css, forms, twitter-bootstrap, checkbox

I am using Twitter Bootstrap inline checkboxes inside a `form-horizontal well well-small`

If I add `pull-left` or `right` to the checkboxes, they are pulled correctly, but dropped out of the `well` element, even though they are nested inside the form. The `pull` works for buttons, but not for inline checkboxes.

I tried putting them inside a control group and using `pull` on the control group but they're still dropped outside the form `well`.

EDIT:

Failing example: http://bbalban.pagodabox.com/snippets/post-fails

Working example: http://bbalban.pagodabox.com/snippets/post-works

It fails when first label is removed or has pull-right. It works when first label is there, but has no pull qualifier.

Thanks.

Comment: can you please paste the code you working with , so that we can help you better

Answer (score 1):

Check, if your checkboxes are aligned by "float" attribute. If yes, then add "overflow: hidden" to the parent element. If no, please, provide a url so that we could test.

**Edit**

The main rule you have to add is:

```
.well { overflow: hidden; }
```

Besides, to correct position of labels and a button, add the following:

```
.well .btn { margin-top: 8px; }
.well label.checkbox { margin: 9px 3px 0 10px; }
```